# How to exit from iframe

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

How to exit from iframe? I have a pages called  `Master.aspx`, `Parent.aspx` (inside that iframe is there), `Child.aspx`. I am calling `Child.aspx` inside `Parent.aspx` page using an iframe.

If `strBillingAddress1` is null then I need to redirect to page `Master.aspx`. It is redirecting but showing inside iframe. I don't want this behavior. I need to open as new page itself?

This is the code:

```
If String.IsNullOrEmpty(Session("strBillingAddress1")) Then
    Response.Redirect("Master.aspx")
    Response.End()
End If
```

Plz help me..
Thanks 
Joby

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `Response.Redirect` is impossible to redirect other than self page. The alternative is to use javascript.

Register a client side script that doin the redirect using the `location`

for example, you can write one of this lines and they do the work.

```
window.top.location.href= 'theLocation';
window.parent.location.href= 'theLocation';
window.top.location.replace( 'theLocation' );
```

Answer (score 1):

Using javascript you can change the top window href value and reload the page.

```
Page.RegisterStartupScript("MyScript", _
   "<script language=javascript>" & _
   "window.top.location.href = (Your Path)'Master.aspx' </script>")
```